# scikit-learn - MinMaxScaler: TypeError: ufunc 'subtract'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a problem using the MinMaxScaler from scikit-learn and cannot interpret the error message correctly, nor can I find information about it.

```
TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' output (typecode 'O') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'd') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
```

For the fit I used a matrix with the following formats:
(275, 821), `numpy.ndarray`, `numpy.float64`

The correctly transformed output was:
(275, 821), `numpy.ndarray`, `numpy.float64`

My input for the "way back" with inverse_transform: 
(206, 821), `numpy.ndarray`, `numpy.float64`

I have done this before and it worked without any problems.
Obviously something about my data is different now, which I can't see and is not related to the format?
I would be happy if someone could explain the error message or give me another hint about what went wrong.

numpy 1.13.1,
pandas 0.20.3,
scikit-learn 0.19.0,
python 2.7.6

Thank you very much!

---

I discovered that the MinMaxScalers attributes have been saved separately by joblib. The min_ attribute appears to be: joblib.numpy_pickle.NDArrayWrapper at 0x7fbc302253d0

For clarification: I save the scaler with joblib and load it before inverse_transform.

---

```
### X and Y are two matrices with values between 0-6000

X_frame = pd.DataFrame(X)
Y_frame= pd.DataFrame(Y)

XYdata = pd.concat([X_frame, Y_frame], axis=1)
XYdata = XYdata.as_matrix()
mm = MinMaxScaler((0,1))
XY_new = mm.fit_transform(XYdata)

np.save('data',XY_new)
filename_scaler = 'scaler.sav'
joblib.dump(mm, filename_scaler)

### There's a prediction algorithm in between I can't add because of company restrictions, the code returns the matrix data 

scaler = joblib.load('scaler.sav')
new_data1 = scaler.inverse_transform(data)
```

Comment: As always, a fully-functional minimal example would be very useful to understand your issue.

Comment: Your new data is somehow resulting in some array of ```dtype=np.object``` (```(typecode 'O')```). But as your description is so sparse, you will need to find it yourself i'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I checked the resulting data multiple times, but there's no object. It's an array with the above specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

```
joblib.dump(mm, filename_scaler, compress =1)
```

The problem was that joblib saved all attributes of the scaler separatly and obviously didn't load them.

Setting the compression level on 1 (True) solved the issue.

Thanks everyone who read and/or who replied.